# In C++ do you need to overload operator== in both directions?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Say I am working with a class:

```
class Foo{
public:
  std:string name;
  /*...*/
}/*end Foo*/
```

and I provide an overload for `operator==`

```
bool operator==(const Foo& fooObj, const std::string& strObj) {
    return (fooObj.name == strObj);
}
```

Do I also need to re-implement the same logic in reverse?

```
bool operator==(const std::string& strObj, const Foo& fooObj) {
    return (strObj == fooObj.name);
}
```

Comment: By the way, in [tag:c++20] you will be able to define just one new operator and the compiler will do the juggling. It's  `operator <=>`.

Comment: related [All you always dreamed to know about operator overloading but never cared to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/5470596).

Comment: The bigger question, IMO, is whether the concept of equality between a `Foo` and a string is a valid concept or an inherent category error. A thing is not equivalent to its name, and the idea that it is is arguably part of  what confuses people so much about pointers and references.

Comment: @cHao in my actual case there is an equivalence between name and "the thing"

Comment: Implement the first comparison operator as a member of `Foo`, **not** as a global freestanding function.  The second operator must simply be implemented as `return objB == objA`

Comment: @StoryTeller - I must have missed the bit where `operator<=>` will reorder arguments of different types (your first comment) - can you point to the section that specifies that?

Comment: @TobySpeight - http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.4

Comment: Thanks @StoryT - I was looking in the `<=>` proposal instead.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

<sub><sub>(C++20 onward)</sub></sub>

With the acceptance of [p1185](https://wg21.link/p1185) into C++20, you don't need to provide more than one overload. The paper made these changes (among others) to the standard:

> **[over.match.oper]**
>
> [3.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.4) - [...] For the `!=` operator ([expr.eq]), the rewritten candidates include all member, non-member, and built-in candidates for the operator `==` for which the rewritten expression `(x == y)` is well-formed when contextually converted to bool using that operator `==`. For the equality operators, the rewritten candidates also include a synthesized candidate, with the order of the two parameters reversed, for each member, non-member, and built-in candidate for the operator `==` for which the rewritten expression `(y == x)` is well-formed when contextually converted to bool using that operator `==`. [ Note: A candidate synthesized from a member candidate has its implicit object parameter as the second parameter, thus implicit conversions are considered for the first, but not for the second, parameter. — end note ] [...]
>
> [8](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#8) [...] If a rewritten candidate is selected by overload resolution for a `!=` operator, `x != y` is interpreted as `(y == x) ? false : true` if the selected candidate is a synthesized candidate with reversed order of parameters, or `(x == y) ? false : true` otherwise, using the selected rewritten `operator==` candidate. If a rewritten candidate is selected by overload resolution for an `==` operator, `x == y` is interpreted as `(y == x) ? true : false` using the selected rewritten `operator==` candidate.

The above means that not only do you *not* need to provide the operator with the order of the operands reversed, you also get `!=` for free! Furthermore, the `operator==` function can be a member if it makes sense. Though as the note in the first paragraph above says, it being a member or free function will affect implicit conversions so you still need to bear that in mind.

---

<sub><sub>(Upto C++17)</sub></sub>

You do if you want to support comparisons where the string is on the left and the `Foo` is on the right. An implementation won't reorder the arguments to an overloaded `operator==` to make it work.

But you can avoid repeating the implementation's logic, though. Assuming your operator should behave as expected:

```
inline bool operator==(const std::string& objA, const Foo& objB) {
    return objB == objA; // Reuse previously defined operator
}
```

Comment: So theoretically one could implement different behaviour for `Foo==String` and `String==Foo`

Comment: Yes, you could. But you definitely shouldn't.

Comment: @StoryTeller Do we get op!= for free with this as !(op==) or should that be implemented both directions as well? (expecting the answer no)

Comment: @hehe3301 - I'm afraid all the overloads you want will need to be implemented explicitly. Although again, the body can be `!(lhs == rhs)`. That's why `operator <=>` generates so much excitement. Because it can cut down on a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: @hehe3301: You can use [boost/operators.hpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/utility/operators.htm), which provides classes to inherit from which fill in operators based on your provided ones. For instance, if you inherit from `equality_comparable<T, U>` and provide `operator==(T, U)`, it will supply `bool operator==(const U&, const T&)`, `bool operator!=(const U&, const T&)`, and `bool operator!=(const T&, const U&)` for you.

Comment: @StoryTeller does the same logic apply to `Foo::operator==(const std::string&)`?

Comment: @DevNull - Interesting that you should ask. There was a proposal merged into C++20 recently that may require a complete update to this answer (and will also address) your comment. I'll ping you once I edited it in.

Comment: @DevNull - As for C++17, the same logic applies. You can't add your own overload to `std::string` so if you want the order reversed, you need to do it yourself. Either directly or indirectly via something like Boost.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you do. Just like in lots of other languages, C++ takes sides and comparisons between two objects of different types will lead to calls to two different comparison operators depending on the order.

Of course, you want them to be consistent and not surprising, so the second should be defined in terms of the first.

Comment: Re: "Just like in other languages": Overloading works sufficiently differently from one language to the next that I don't think this sort of sweeping statement is helpful.